# System.ArgumentException in System.Drawing.dll "Parameter is invalid"

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am creating a wallpaper changer that selects the newest wallpaper based off some criteria set by the user. Everything should be working fine, in fact I found out the error is caused by not disposing of the image before setting it again so I did that but it still happened.

Here is a snippet of my code that makes two copies of the image. One for a history grid as a thumbnail and one for later if the user wants to save the image.

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(url);

    if (bytes.Count().Equals(0))
    {
        changeWallpaperTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        memoryStreamImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        ms.Dispose();
        ms.Close();

        if (currentWallpaper != null)
        {
            currentWallpaper.Dispose();
        }

        currentWallpaper = new Bitmap(memoryStreamImage);
        dataGridNumber += 1;

        historyDataGrid.Rows.Insert(0, new Bitmap(memoryStreamImage, new Size(100, 100)), title, dataGridNumber, threadID);
        memoryStreamImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215610/image-propertyitems-and-disposed-memorystream), basically don't dispose/close memory streams that you pass to images.

Comment: You are making copies of *img*.  But you are not disposing the *img* object at all.  That's liable to bomb your program when the garbage collector doesn't keep you out of trouble.  For the exact same reason you found that disposing currentWallpaper was necessary.  You also need to check that *objBitmap* gets disposed somewhere.

Comment: @HansPassant The error is coming directly from "memoryStreamImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);"

I changed the code a bit to make img a global scope, recheck my edited code. It still is causing problems with my edited code.

Comment: Now the first comment is appropriate, keep the memory stream available until *after* you disposed the image.

Comment: @HansPassant I found the problem. What was supposed to be an image, and even after a check to make sure the bytes where a valid image some how a web page got through causing a false positive error. Fixed it now. On the bright side of my code I fixed a memory leak.... thats what not disposing is right, memory leak?